# Page navigation missing in "Unanswered Questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed

Suddenly the page navigation seems to be missing for "Unanswered Questions" on stackoverflow.com. It's still available for the normal "Questions" page though.

The links were there just a few minutes ago, but disappeared on a page refresh. Checked in both Firefox 17 and Chrome 23, both logged in and not.

Comment: They want you to provide answers for all the questions on the first page before you are allowed to see more! :-P ... (and yes, I see it too).

Comment: Given that we speak about [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered), nope, I can see the pagination.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Try [this instead](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hands up, that was me: some significant internal reworking in that area earlier, and I passed the wrong "total" into the paging controls (I passed the "total on this page", rather than the "total total" - which of course means it thinks there is only one page needed). Will be deploying momentarily.

Comment: (all deployed now)